# Shopify Storefront API access cart created in web store

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

So... I've been playing around with Shopify's Storefront API. I have a store... when something is added to the cart, I receive a token which I assume is the cart ID. I log this ID out to my browser console and copy it.

I've made a private app, and I can query products over the Storefront API - so I thought I'd have a go at retrieving a cart by its ID (the one I copied from the browser).

I encode the cartId in base64... just because other examples were base64 strings. Sure enough the ID is correctly decoded in the error message:

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Invalid global id '76f8efad975def03680e8de12442a65e'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "query",
        "node",
        "id"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "argumentLiteralsIncompatible",
        "typeName": "CoercionError"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know what the 'global id' is - but here is my query.

```js
const cartId = 'NzZmOGVmYWQ5NzVkZWYwMzY4MGU4ZGUxMjQ0MmE2NWU'

   const query = `{
    node(id: "${cartId}") {
      id
      ... on Checkout {
        id
        ready
        currencyCode
        subtotalPrice
        taxesIncluded
        totalTax
        totalPrice
        lineItems(first: 250) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
              quantity
              variant {
                id
                price
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`
```

Is my syntax correct? Or, am I barking up the wrong tree trying to retrieve a cart that was created in website store land, and not Storefront API land?

If it is possible for my app to access any carts created by visitors to the Shopify site by querying the cart token/id, that would be a game changer.

** Edit **

I refactored my code - so it uses a webhook to grab the cart ID.

But I receive the following error:

'Invalid global id `981820079255243500`

I read somewhere (I forget where - its been a rabbit hole) that Storefront API uses a different ID for accessing the same cart to the one provided by the webhook? Is that true, and if so - how do I access it?

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import Client from 'shopify-buy';
global.fetch = fetch;

// ........ removed for brevity


const client = Client.buildClient({
  domain: shopUrl,
  storefrontAccessToken: accessToken
});

// we need to base64 our ID for storefront api
const base64Encode = (data) => {
  const buff = new Buffer(data);
  return buff.toString('base64');
}


const getCart = async (cartId) => {
try {
  const cartBuffer64 = base64Encode(cartId);
  const myCart = await client.checkout.fetch(cartBuffer64)
  console.log(myCart)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    throw e
  }
}

// noddy express app to test if this works
app.post('/hook', (req, res) => {
  // todo: validate webhook
  console.log(req.body.id)
  getCart(req.body.id)
  return res.status(200).end()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send any created carts to your App. One, you can assign the webhook to cart/create, with cart/update for changes, or two, you could send the ID/token to an App Proxy. Anything you do with StorefrontAPI, Where you connect it to this App, could also provide info. So you have a lot of choices here. Just be careful about your security.

Comment: Thanks David - so I refactored my code to use a webhook, and the ID comes in... however, Storefront API rejects it... it says the ID is invalid.

Comment: It makes sense to me, that the two would be separate. Imagine a rogue StorefrontAPI token that could theoretically read any cart by ID? Not something a merchant would appreciate!

Comment: So while you can send any created cart to your app - you can't request the cart, or manipulate the contents of the cart. So there is no way to read carts created in my own site with my own app...

Plan B it is then - use Storefront API for everything. That's a pain.

Comment: Well, to each their own right. Storefront is meant to provide carts without online store. Anything online store can do, Storefront can do, and vice versa. So really, there need not be such heartache right.

Comment: Except you can't write to carts with the online store's Admin API.
Storefront API gives you much more power - but you need to replace the entire frontend.

I'm playing about with proxying everything to my app, and have it return to the site... but this makes it impossible to cleanly integrate as an app solution... it means hijacking every add to cart and remove from cart method - have them post to my external app. and then, modify the callbacks of each to take a response from my app. It's not something that could be "drop in" on every site. I'd need to supply my own template.

Comment: Yes. Well.. You picked this battle. So you get to play with all those moving parts. It is the fun part of the job.

Comment: Now building my own cart - much easier to get what I want, and more maintainable. Built on Phoenix so I could hit the ground running. Already have an api for inventory and cart functionality done. Payments today, and discount codes. Leaning on tax jar for tax stuff and stripe for payments, and DespatchBay for shipping. Will make utilities for refunds when needed.